# Convert date in a String variable to Long

Tags: excel, vba

I have a variable called `repDate` which today is equal to "5/1/2020" as a string.

I tried to convert it to a `Long` so I can compare it to a date in the file

```
rDtLng = CLng(repDate)
```

I get an error

> Type Mismatch

This is where I am doing the comparing. The rest works.

```vb
'repDate equals "5/1/2020", currently

rDtLng = CLng(repDate)
.
.
.
'Delete charge offs
For w = rwCnt To 3 Step -1
    Do While .Cells(w, napbRng.Column).Value2 <= 0 And .Cells(w, apbRng.Column).Value2 <= 0
        If .Cells(w, matDtRng.Column).Value2 = "" Then Exit Do
        If .Cells(w, matDtRng.Column).Value2 < rDtLng Then
            .Rows(w).Delete shift:=xlShiftUp
        Else: Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
Next w
```

Comment: Why `Long` and not `Date`? Use `CDate`. You can then `CLng` if you want... but I don't see why you would. Math works on `Date`s too... and the more I look at this, the more I feel like you could just use `Range.AutoFilter` with a date filter, and then delete visible rows.

Comment: @BigBen - Do you want to put your comment into an answer so you can get even more reputation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CLng` expects a numeric input, which the *text-that-looks-like-a-date* `"5/1/2020"` is not.

You can convert that to an actual date using `CDate` and then perform mathematical operations on it, including the existing `<` comparison.

Though if I understand what your end goal is, you might consider `Range.AutoFilter` with a date filter, and then deleting visible rows, instead of your current `Do` loop approach.

*Side note*: you could `CLng(CDate("5/1/2020"))` and the result would be `43952`, but that's an unnecessary step, as you can do math with dates directly.

Answer (score 0):

Use DateValue() Function.

```
Sub test()
    Dim myDate As Long
    Dim str As String

    str = "5/1/2020"
    myDate = DateValue(str)

    If myDate = DateSerial(2020, 5, 1) Then
        MsgBox "OK"
    End If

End Sub
```